# How does sum function work in python with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, generator, iterable

I was using sum function in python, and i am clear about it's general structure **sum(iterable, start)**  , but i am unable to get the logic behind the following code

```
test = sum(5 for i in range(5) )
print("output:  ", test)
```

output:  25

Please can anyone describe what is happening here, basically here 5 is getting multiplied with 5, and same pattern is there for every sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is shorthand for:

```
test = sum((5 for i in range(5)))
```

The removal of extra parentheses is syntactic sugar: it has no impact on your algorithm.

The `(5 for i in range(5))` component is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which, on each iteration, yields the value 5. Your generator expression has 5 iterations in total, as defined by `range(5)`. Therefore, the generator expression yields 5 exactly 5 times.

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), as the docs indicate, accepts any *iterable*, even those *not* held entirely in memory. Generators, and by extension generator expressions, are memory efficient. Therefore, your logic will sum 5 exactly 5 times, which equals 25.

A convention when you don't use a variable in a closed loop is to denote that variable by underscore (`_`), so usually you'll see your code written as:

```
test = sum(5 for _ in range(5))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i am able to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a list to the `sum` function so you can make something like this:

```
test = sum((1,23,5,6,100))
print("output:  ", test)
```

And you get `135`.

So with your "for loop" you get a list and put that list to the `sum` function and you get the sum of the list. The real `sum` function uses yield insight and use every value and sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is summing 5 repeativily for every "i" on range(5). Meaning, this code is equivalent to n*5, being n the size of range(n).